# HOW TO Use .DRF as a target / link

Tags: html

I am creating an intranet site at work and would like to link button to files that are in a document management environment (Open Text). I created a .DRF (which is just a reference to the file in the DM). I want the user to be able to click a button and the document to either open or download from the DM. I know I can simply copy the docs and put them in the folder with my pages but that defeats the purpose of the DM.

I know the .DRF works because I can click it and the file opens but when I use it as the target or an href it just opens a  page in the browser with the doc #. If any one has any experience with this I would appreciate some pointers.

Here is the code I'm using

```
        <a><form method="get" action="DOCS-94710.DOC.DRF" target="_blank">
        <button type="submit">94710</button>
        </form></a>
```

Thanks,
Shannon

Comment: Wrapping the form in an A tag isn't going to achieve a lot :). If you're trying to open the .DRF then having it as the action of your form isn't going to do much either. Have you tried just <a href='DOCS-94710.DOC.DRF'>94710</a>? Also, is the .DRF file in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me. Yes, the .drf is in the same file. I can click on it (while in the file) and it opens right up. I also tried the code as you suggested. It creates a link that opens a web page with only the doc #. All methods seem to almost work but there must be a silver bullet out there somewhere. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution while we were setting up our intranet. Create a repository folder on your intranet, upload your (DM) drf files to your intranet, and hyperlink them internally to your intranet. If you have created them properly, it will know which native app to launch it in and would respect the security settings the way you set them up in DM. This was a game changer and works with both IE and Chrome browsers.